# Javascript refresh + countdown text

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript in the header to refresh the page

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
```

and in the body tag

```
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
```

My question is how do I add a text showing the countdown to refresh the page

x seconds to refresh

Comment: What have you tried? Search the web for "javascript countdown", there are so many examples…

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Does this suit your needs?

```
(function countdown(remaining) {
    if(remaining <= 0)
        location.reload(true);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
})(5); // 5 seconds
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgHJe/4/)

Comment: this seems to work in the fiddle but when i added it to my page it doesnt even show the text nor does it refresh,

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos You need an HTML element in your page with the id "countdown" for it to write the time remaining into. You can modify the Javascript of course if you want to write it into a different element.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos See the div in the HTML section of the fiddle

Comment: I added the div element in the body <div id="countdown"></div>

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos The script also has to be after that div in the HTML, so that the div exists when the script starts. You can put it in a script tag immediately after, like `<div id="countdown"></div><script>...`

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos Alternatively you can check that the element exists before trying to assign to it's innerHTML property.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos I'm looking at your site right now. You need the script to be after your `<div id="countdown"></div>`. Try making the script the last thing before your closing `</body>` tag and it should work.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos No problemo :)

Comment: You need to stop the timer to avoid reloading over and over once the countdown is below zero.

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk The page will reload every 5 seconds, no more, no less.

Comment: ADD <span id="countdown">5</span> in your HTML.

Comment: I tried this but then it got into a loop trying to refresh the page every second, so I modified the code to prevent this: `function countdown(remaining) {
   if (remaining <= 0) {
    location.reload(true)
   } else {
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    setTimeout(function () { countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
   }
  };`

Answer (score 8):

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/vKmUN/9/)

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
   if (timeoutPeriod > 0) {
       timeoutPeriod -= 1;
       document.body.innerHTML = timeoutPeriod + ".." + "<br />";
       // or
       document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeoutPeriod + ".." + "<br />";
   } else {
       clearInterval(timer);
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
       };
   }, 1000);
};
timedRefresh(10);
```

I don't really see why you would use `setTimeout` for this purpose.

Comment: almost works, but it hides the content of the page whilst it starts to count down, have a look http://uelhub.com/fingerprinting/

Comment: This seems to me a better solution than remain reloading over and over.

Comment: Perfect thanks. To the people not getting this to work make sure you noticed the // or bit in the code.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question has been already answered some time ago, but I was looking for similar code but with a longer (minutes) interval. It didn't come up in searches I did so this is what I came up with and thought I'd share:

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDwTj/)

**Javascript**

```
function checklength(i) {
    'use strict';
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

var minutes, seconds, count, counter, timer;
count = 601; //seconds
counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
    'use strict';
    count = count - 1;
    minutes = checklength(Math.floor(count / 60));
    seconds = checklength(count - minutes * 60);
    if (count < 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 'Next refresh in ' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ';
    if (count === 0) {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to run the timeout every second, update the DOM and only reload when you need to:

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
var i = 5000;
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    i = timeoutPeriod;
    updateDom();
}
//   -->

function updateDom(){
    body.innerHTML = i;
    i--;
    if (i==0){
        location.reload(true);
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(updateDom, 1000);
    }
}
//   -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because my page did not refresh within a second (in dev) I slightly modified answer of Paul to:

```
(function countdown(remaining) {
    if(remaining === 0)
        location.reload(true);
    if(remaining > 0)
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
      setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
})(30); // 30 seconds
```

What was happening was that the counter was issuing new GETs every second and the page never got a change to load. The extra test solved that.