# how to calculate page refresh count in javascript use only localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to calculate page refresh count in javascript using localstorage only.

I am developing one website. In that website I have to reload the page on any browser simultaneously the count will be increased. if the count equal to 6 enable popup.

Comment: Use `localstorage`.

Comment: @Mohammad — How will one identify that user had `refreshed` the page ?

Comment: please share an example of what you've tried and any issues that you might be facing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532577/javascript-refresh-countdown-text

Comment: you have to do that with the cookie first to check that user is same one. then jquery counter.

Comment: @santosh that not a solution that ask.

Comment: if i am refresh the page 5 time and you opne that page on your pc then you got the pop up in first time because for page that was a 6 time. they need for the specific user.

Comment: Any one give a working example with local storage

Comment: Something like this: `var count = localStorage.getItem("count");
    count = count ? count+1 : 0;
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    if (count == 6){//Do something}`

Comment: unacceptable question with too many possible answers

Comment: You can find something similar to your requirement here ( not exactly though) How do I detect a page refresh using jquery? Hope this helps..

Comment: @ Ted upload anyone working example

Comment: @ Mohammad It doesn't work. Check and update working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below link will be help you out.

[blog] http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/js-session/index.html 
[blog] http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/js-session/session.js

Comment: It work fine. But i need to implement in local storage.

Answer (score 5):

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
  var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0);

  localStorage.setItem('counter', ++count)
}, false);

if (localStorage.getItem('counter') == 6) {
 alert('You refreshed page 6 times')
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. check it. and upload working code.

Comment: If you don't now how localStorage work - it's not a my problem. This function is setting up variable in localStorage and you can get it from it. Or you need to learn JS and don't talk to me like that.

Comment: I am not hurting you. I am just said. If you have to work on that upload that. that's it

Comment: @ ArtemKh edit your answer.

Comment: @Dhaarani I don't understand what do you want, I added code where it's calculate number of page refreshing. You can get that variable and open up popup or something else.

Comment: if count is equal to 6 the popup will trigger

Comment: if (localStorage.getItem('counter') == 6) { // Open popup }

Comment: ok add to your code